# Best Way to Mount/Access an S3 Bucket as Local Directory from Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-s3

##### The Usecase

Training and persisting some machine learning models with tensorflow. The machine learning models must be saved in some s3 bucket directory. Tensorflow itself persists the models in directories using the `model.save` method. So I want to pass the s3 directory directly to this method.

##### Solutions Considered

###### S3FS Fuse

I have used it, but when I try to run it inside a docker container, seems the container itself must run in `privilieged` mode to enable it. This privileged mode is not always available.

###### S3FS PyPi

I have not even used it, but it claims to be feature incomplete. Also, it is not clear whether it is compatible with tensorflow, and support all the POSIX interfaces necessary for tensorflow to save and load the model correctly.

Some legacy codes I see use boto3 clients, but they seem to operate on a per file basis, also the interface seems clunky as opposed to convenient local filesystem read write. Realistically, tensorflow saves a lot of files in different formats inside its directory, so replicating the exact directory hierarchy in s3 seems difficult.

So what are the alternatives I should look at?

Comment: You could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to copy a whole folder of files to S3. It uses boto3 underneath rather than 'mounting' S3 as a drive. If you want to do it straight from Python, then boto3 is the official AWS Python SDK.